# Prepared Statement and SQL different results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using designing a system to get the most recent update of a status that uses `INSERT` statements. The Prepared statement block looks like this.

```
$load_status = $db->prepare('SELECT `statusID` FROM  `tor_status` WHERE  `requestID`=? ORDER BY  `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1');
$load_status->bind_param('i',$request_id);
$load_status->execute();
$load_status->bind_result($request_status);
$load_details->fetch();

$status_denied="";
$status_approved="";
$selected = " checked";
//Preselect approved/denied status if applies
switch ($request_status){
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        $status_pproved = $selected;
        break;
    case 2:
        $status_denied = $selected;
        break;
}
```

However, when run using this data

```
| changeID | timestamp | requestID | statusID |
 | 1 | 6/10/2014 11:17 | 1 | 0 | 
 | 2 | 6/10/2014 11:17 | 2 | 0 | 
 | 3 | 6/10/2014 11:33 | 3 | 0 | 
 | 4 | 6/10/2014 11:41 | 4 | 0 | 
 | 5 | 6/10/2014 13:24 | 5 | 0 | 
 | 9 | 6/17/2014 12:30 | 6 | 0 | 
 | 10 | 6/17/2014 13:35 | 7 | 0 | 
 | 11 | 8/9/2014 15:09 | 8 | 0 | 
 | 12 | 8/9/2014 15:13 | 3 | 1 | 
 | 13 | 8/9/2014 15:14 | 3 | 0 | 
 | 14 | 8/9/2014 15:14 | 6 | 0 | 
 | 15 | 8/9/2014 15:28 | 7 | 2 | 
 | 16 | 8/9/2014 15:29 | 6 | 1 |
```

Running an SQL statement in the DB returns "1" and the prepared returns "0" when looking for the requestID of 6. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't suppose you INSERTED the 6 -> 1 record in the DB and didn't commit the transaction by any chance?

Comment: All of the data is inserted, finalized, etc. The data is from a csv export and find&replace to make it (more) legible here. It's in, just a question of why.

Comment: what is timestamp's type, looking at the data you pasted, it is not a mysql timestamp so ordering by it will return unexpected results.

Comment: @CodeBird While that may be true, they are all different for `request_id=6` so the results should be consistent.

Comment: @TechHeadDJ The fact that you used the word finalized and not committed worries me..

Comment: @Arth They are all the result of previous INSERT statements and tweaks. They are there, but I'm not sure of the difference between finalized and committed. It was INSERT'ed, not tentatively INSERT'ed. I'm not even sure HOW to do that.

Comment: @TechHeadDJ Ah cool.. no worries, perhaps finalized has the same meaning. It is possible (if auto-commit is off) to run some inserts on the DB in one session and then select the new data without committing it. This data will be invisible to another session. I think I have found your issue however in the code after the query! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this might be your problem:

```
$status_approved="";
...
case 0:
    break;
case 1:
    $status_pproved = $selected;
    break;
```

You are never setting `$status_approved` just a new, presumably unread variable `$status_pproved`, so case `0` and `1` behave the same.

**UPDATE**

Should:

```
$load_details->fetch();
```

Be:

```
$load_status->fetch();
```

Comment: Even with the `$status_approved` fixed, I am printing the data into a javascript `console.log(` which returns "Status is 0" with the `$request_status` variable. So it isn't that I'm making assumptions, that _is_ what is being returned by the query.

Comment: @TechHeadDJ Fair enough, see update. I'm fairly sure it isn't what is being returned by the query.

Comment: The "details" to "status" is EXACTLY what did it. Thank you @Arth, you've been a life-saver. Any flavor of choice?